# Latex: Extracting the sty files of all the used packages

Tags: latex, package

So after writing a large .tex file and using many packages I want to archive everything, not just the .tex .jpg  files, but also the .sty files.

This is because sometimes some options in the sty files are changed, and then I can't compile the file.

The "problem" is that in using Ubuntu, I already installed all the packages in my system.
I don't want to have to copy them manually.
Is there a program that can do this automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-filesused, quote:

> All the files used by this document When you’re sharing a document
>   with someone else (perhaps as part of a co-development cycle) it’s as
>   well to arrange that both correspondents have the same set of
>   auxiliary files, as well as the document in question. Your
>   correspondent obviously needs the same set of files (if you use the
>   [`url`](https://ctan.org/pkg/url) package, she has to have [`url`](https://ctan.org/pkg/url) too, for example). But
>   suppose you have a bug-free version of the `shinynew` package but her
>   copy is still the unstable original; until you both realise what is
>   happening, such a situation can be very confusing.
>
> The simplest solution is the LaTeX `\listfiles` command. This places a
>   list of the files used and their version numbers in the log file. If
>   you extract that list and transmit it with your file, it can be used
>   as a check-list in case that problems arise.
>
> Note that `\listfiles` only registers things that are input by the
>   “standard” LaTeX mechanisms (`\documentclass`, `\usepackage`,
>   `\include`, `\includegraphics` and so on). The `\input` command, as
>   modified by LaTeX and used, with LaTeX syntax, as:
>
> ```
> \input{mymacros}
> ```
>
> records file details for `mymacros.tex`, but if you use TeX primitive
>   syntax for `\input`, as:
>
> ```
> \input mymacros
> ```
>
> `mymacros.tex` won’t be recorded, and so won’t listed by `\listfiles`
>   — you’ve bypassed the mechanism that records its use.
>
> The [`snapshot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) package helps the owner of a LaTeX document obtain
>   a list of the external dependencies of the document, in a form that
>   can be embedded at the top of the document. The intended use of the
>   package is the creation of archival copies of documents, but it has
>   application in document exchange situations too.
>
> The `bundledoc` system uses the [`snapshot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) to produce an archive
>   (e.g., `tar.gz` or `zip`) of the files needed by your document; it
>   comes with configuration files for use with TeX Live-Unix and MiKTeX.
>   It’s plainly useful when you’re sending the first copy of a document.
>
> The `mkjobtexmf` finds which files are used in a “job”, either via the
>   `-recorder` option of TeX, or by using the (Unix) command `strace` to
>   keep an eye on what TeX is doing. The files thus found are copied (or
>   linked) to a directory which may then be saved for transmission or
>   archiving.

Answer (score 2):

Latex logfiles indicate all files loaded as follows:

1. Files specified using absolute paths are shown `(\$PATH` followed by whitespace (a space or a newline; I think Tex forbids whitespace in paths, certainly paths with whitespace are a pairn to pass to `\input`);
2. Local paths are the same except they have a dot: `(.\$PATH` followed by whitespace
3. Fonts are shown within `<...>`.

You can easily scrape these filenames out of the .log file.